# Passing value of arrayList from a void method to arrayList in another class

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, void

I have a class named `Preprocessing` and has a method called Process()

, it has an ArrayList called datatweets that contains my data.

```
public void Process(){
 //the process...
   datatweets.add(mydata);
}
```

then I try to pass the datatweets and the value(my data) to another ArrayList on the different class. I've tried using getter method such as:

```
public ArrayList getMyList(){
       return datatweets;
}
```

but it still doesn't print any value when I call it. please tell me what is wrong, and what should I do?

here's what i do to call the arrayList:

```
Preprocessing data = new Preprocessing();
        ArrayList<String> dataset = new ArrayList<>();
        dataset = data.getMyList();

        for(int a=0;a<dataset.size();a++){
            System.out.println(dataset.get(a));
        }
```

Comment: Show us, how You do that.

Comment: could you add the code where you try to pass the datatweets and the value(my data) to another arrayList on the different class?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve here. Please elaborate.

Comment: i have edited my question guys, i'm sorry if its unclear. any help please

Comment: Where are you calling Process()? Where are you adding values to your Preprocessing-object(datatweets) before you start looping?

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you have an class named "Preprocessing". Now you should have "datatweets" as your instance variable of the class.

Now you should create an object of Preprocessing and call the method "Process". In the method process you should fill the arraylist "datatweets". Process method should contain below code.

```
if(this.dataTweets == null)
 this.dataTweets = new ArrayList<>();

this.dataTweets.add(myData);
```

Once the datatweets is filled by calling the process method. You should have getter method in same class which should return datatweets

```
public List<String> getDataTweets(){
return this.dataTweets;
}
```

Now the main function should look like this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Preprocessing preprocessor = new Preprocessing();
preprocessor.Process();
List<String> dataTweets = preprocessor.getDataTweets();
 //Now iterate over this you will surely get data.
}
```

You class Preprocessor should be like this

```
public class Preprocessor{
 private List<String> dataTweets;
 public void process(){
    //processing
   this.dataTweets.add(data);
 }
 public List<String> getDataTweets(){
   return this.dataTweets;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer man, but my it print a blank page on the console, it's just like my arraylist i passed from the previous class (Preprocessing) is empty. what do you think? @Rohit

Comment: Please check if you adding any values to dataTweets array. Just try debug or atleast sysout to console the values that your adding to arraylist. If nothing is going to get added to that arraylist then you are going to get empty arraylist and then empty screen.

Comment: i add myData to dataTweets arrayList in the method Process(). when i sysout it prints the value in the console. BUT when i sysout it from another class it just prints [ ] which is my arrayList is empty right?  @Rohit

Comment: Just check my answer again. I have the class defination on how it should look. Are you doing it same way ?

Comment: yes i'm doing exactly what you've said. Anyway, the method Process() is a void method, is that matter ? @Rohit